# MVVM and pivot control in WP

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I'm new to WP8 & MVVM. I have an app, that has a pivot control with 3 pivot elements on main screen. For example it will be store-app and pivots are "catalog", "cart", and "categories".

Is it right (in terms of mvvm) if I build smth like:

Models:

- CatalogElem
- CartElem
- Category

ViewModels:

- CatalogElemViewModel (contains an ObservableCollection of CatalogElem)
- CartElemViewModel (contains an ObservableCollection of CartElem)
- CategoryViewModel (contains an ObservableCollection of CategoryElem)
- MainViewModel (contains CatalogElemViewModel, CartElemViewModel, CategoryViewModel)

Views:

- CatalogView
- CartView
- CategoryView
- MainView (contains 3 views, that described as UserControls)

Comment: That sounds about right. I'd name them like so : CartViewModel (Cart model), CatalogViewModel (Catalog model), CategoriesViewModel (Category model).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page (MainView) with pivot control (3 pivot items) is just one View (one View = one ViewModel).

You need only `MainViewModel` contains three `ObservableCollection`.

Models:

- Catalog
- Cart
- Category

ViewModels

- MainViewModel

View

- MainView